# Do I need nvidia driver for Dell Inspiron 5720?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, dell

So I bought my Dell Inspiron 5720 month ago. Sure the first thing I did was purging Windows and installing Ubuntu 12.04. Now, I use it for a month already. Only driver I installed during all this time was Broadcom adapter driver so that Wi-Fi could work.
So I never really installed video adapter driver, even though my laptop has a powerful NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M video adapter .System settings say that Intel® Ivybridge Mobile adapter is used instead.
I never really had any problems with laptop performance capacity: movies play very good, web and IDEs work fast. I never played on it though.

My question is: Do I need to install Nvidia adapter drivers? Why should I do it?
Thanks!

**UPD:**
Forgot to mention: I don't have anything in my Additional Drivers section.
Here is how it looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/tpFIg.png]

`lspci` results:
[image]

`lspci -v` gives

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge
>   Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])    Subsystem:
>   Dell Device 0565  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
>     Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]     Memory at
>   e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]   I/O ports at 4000
>   [size=64]     Expansion ROM at  [disabled]    Capabilities:
>      Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel modules: i915

and

> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1140 (rev a1)
>     Subsystem: Dell Device 0565     Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16  Memory at
>   f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]    Memory at c0000000
>   (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit,
>   prefetchable) [size=32M]  I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]    Expansion ROM
>   at  [disabled]   Capabilities:    Kernel
>   modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at these resources: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

I believe your laptop has the on-demand discrete GPU feature called "optimus"

This is currently not well supported by NVIDIA under linux. Bumblebee gives you a work around.
NVIDIA has made indications that they are working on a Linux Optimus driver, but it has yet to be released

Comment: Thank you! I installed it just now. Do I understand it right that I need to use $optirun every time I need to actually use Nvidia graphic card for some program?

Comment: correct, if you want certain applications to always run on the Nvidia GPU, you could use a command-line alias. See doc here: http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#alias